# Notation of signed measure $d\upsilon=fd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm confused about the notion of $d\upsilon$ when defining a signed measure. In Folland's real analysis, he introduces

> We shall use the notation $d\upsilon= fd\mu$ to express the relationship $\upsilon(E) = \int_E fd\mu$. Sometimes, by a slight abuse of language, we shall refer to "the signed measure $f d\mu$".

I agree that the expressions $d\upsilon= fd\mu$ and $\upsilon(E) = \int_E fd\mu$ are equivalent if I use the intuition from calculus. However, later Folland mentions

> The measure $d\lambda = d\upsilon - fd \mu$ (**which is positive since $f\in\mathcal{F}$**) is
> singular with respect to $\mu$.

So my question is: What is the "which" in the part "which is positive since ..." referring to? I can understand it if it's $\lambda$. However, if it's $d\lambda$, then what does it mean?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether we call a measure $\lambda$ or $d\lambda$, it still refers to the same thing. So it's the same to say $\lambda$ is positive or $d\lambda$ is positive. If we are defining a measure and saying it's positive in one swoop, it's just easier to say

> The measure $d\lambda = d\upsilon - fd \mu$ (**which is positive since $f\in\mathcal{F}$**) is
> singular with respect to $\mu$.

rather than

> The measure $\lambda$ defined by $\lambda(E) = \upsilon(E) - \int_Ef\,d \mu$ (**which is positive since $f\in\mathcal{F}$**) is
> singular with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks! So can I say the "$d$" in $d\lambda$ has nothing to do with the meaning of "$d$" in $fd\mu$? I used to think the former means something like "small change in the value of $\lambda$"...

Comment: @sam2018: It's strictly notation